# Sonarqube "Partially covered by tests" in Grails controller method

Tags: grails, controller, sonarqube, code-coverage

When sonarqube analyzes the test coverage in Grails groovy code the last line in the controller's methods always indicates that only 1 of 8 conditions has been covered. For example, in the attached method it is simply rendering a view and yet Sonarqube complains indicating "Partially covered by test (1 of 8 conditions)". Any idea why Sonarqube interprets that there are 8 conditions and how to cover them?

```
class AdminController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: 'POST', update: 'PUT']
    MenuDefinitionAdminService menuDefinitionAdminService
    AdminService adminService

    def index() {
      menuDefinitionAdminService.buildBreadCrumbForAdminIndex()
      render view: 'index'  // Here Sonarqube says "Partially covered by test (1 of 8 conditions)"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.